# C# how to get non-system assemblies

Tags: c#, assemblies

I need to instantiate an object that is defined only in the program assemblies or mscorlib, and not in any other system assemblies. Currently I'm doing this:

```
Type type;
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
{
    string fullName = name + "," + assembly.FullName;
    type = Type.GetType(fullName);
    if (type != null) break;
}
if (type != null) 
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Is there a way to optimize this loop to skip the system assemblies (but not mscorlib)? I need to call this multiple times.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to change your variable name for the Assemblies iterator.  You may get flagged.  :)

Comment: there I changed it, thanks for the warning

Comment: Don't write code like this.  It will randomly fail to create the type, depending on when it is called.  Right after program start, just a few assemblies are loaded.  Some types can never be created, even though they exist, because it requires loading the assembly first.

Comment: Some further reading to help understand why the comment by @HansPassant is important: [When does a .NET Assembly Dependency get loaded?](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded#AssemblyLoading)

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this:

```
  loadedAssemblies = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                   where
                     assembly.ManifestModule.Name != "<In Memory Module>"                         
                     && !assembly.FullName.StartsWith("System")
                     && !assembly.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft")
                     && assembly.Location.IndexOf("App_Web") == -1
                     && assembly.Location.IndexOf("App_global") == -1
                     && assembly.FullName.IndexOf("CppCodeProvider") == -1
                     && assembly.FullName.IndexOf("WebMatrix") == -1
                     && assembly.FullName.IndexOf("SMDiagnostics") == -1
                     && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(assembly.Location)
                   select assembly).ToList();
```

Once you have "loadedAssemblies" you can do what you need to do with this.

If you're calling this multiple times, then store the loaded assemblies in a variable so you don't query each time but rather just iterate over the list.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My concern with this approach is that there is no stopping the users of my api to create their assemblies starting with name Systemblahblah.

Comment: @Dona, you have provided absolutely no context for a "concern" of any kind. Your question was about optimizing the process to load system assemblies and I believe this does that. I can't address your concern without a whole lot more details including what exactly you're doing and who your users are (as in what do they do with your application - if they are "users" they have no business messing here. What control you have over this whole thing etc.

Comment: I have no control, I provide a DLL, the users of my DLL define class types on their assemblies. I know the name of the class type so I can instantiate it, but I have to search it from their assemblies, I have no control on how they name their assemblies. So I can't hard code the assembly filtering based on names, I was hoping there is some property on the assembly to tell me that it's a system assembly (that is provided by the language) as opposed to a program assembly.

Comment: @Dona, no there is no such thing. I'd be surprised that people would name their assemblies System.dll or Microsoft.xxx.dll and similar. I also think you're being overly concerned and if it comes to that you can always document and stipulate that user assemblies don't have names starting with System or Microsoft etc. But either ways, I think you have the answer to your question. You other concerns warrant another question

Answer (score 1):

You can call Load(). From the remarks:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58.aspx

> If a version of the requested assembly is already loaded, this method returns the loaded assembly, even if a different version is requested.

However, under the hood, I'm not sure if this is faster than your O(n) loop (or even any different). You might want to test them both out. If you need to run this loop for multiple assemblies then I suggest running the loop once and finding all the assemblies you need in that go. If you are running this loop multiple times for a same assembly then I suggest a singleton type pattern where you can get the reference once and never look again.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all of your program assemblies you could just make a collection of those.  You can also load Mscorlib.dll without having to iterate through every assembly.  In essence I'm proposing whitelisting as opposed to blacklisting.

`Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Mscorlib.dll");`

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/prog_csharp_ch18/index.html?page=5